# No Key generated with CTP and Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I am working with Entity Framework 4, CTP 5, and an existing database.  I am using Database First (so I have an edmx model, and I am using the DbContext code generation template).

My database has primary keys defined (they are not identity, they are strings, and it's a legacy system, so I cannot change that).

When EF generates my entity objects, there are no Key attributes on them, and I get errors indicating that there is no key (I'm usign this with WCF RIA services -- or attempting to, anyway).  I also looked in the DbContext, and there is no key mapping created there either.

I know I could go in and modify the T4 template, but I'm assuming that I must be doing something wrong -- the MS template surely isn't just ignoring PK's, is it?

Comment: Is it doing it on all your tables or just the ones with strings as PKs?

Comment: Hard to tell -- this database uses artificial keys, so every table has a string key.

Comment: It looks as though the T4 template really doesn't specify keys.  So either you never get keys with MS's DbContext T4, or maybe the metaworkspace doesn't set up keys from the edmx file if they are not identity?